# How can I send data to an already running thread with a loop in python?

Tags: android, python, multithreading

So here I got a question! How can I send and receive data from a simple thread who's job is to keep playing songs!? I want a way to send data to the thread to stop iterating a list of songs. It can be a file descriptor, variable(global), properties/options, database entry, or even an event.

Here is the code:

```
def ControlPlay(ControlAction):

   SongList = DarkCore.mediaPlayList().result
   while ControlAction:
     for Song in SongList:
         if DarkCore.mediaIsPlaying(Song).result == False:
             print "Now Playing:" , Song 
             DarkCore.mediaPlayStart(Song)
             while DarkCore.mediaIsPlaying(Song).result:
               continue


import android # Python For Android
DarkCore = android.Android()

import threading               
t = threading.Thread(target=ControlPlay, args=(True,))
t.start()
```

I may get a **Stop** from multiple sources(devices) using different protocols like wifi via socket(ssh tunnel), bluetooth or serial that extend over a range of protocols and actions. All I want is a way to identify and declare an action based on what another thread or main loop sends.

A simple explanation.. Thanks for your understanding! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want a way for a running thread to stop an iteration, probably you might wanna take a look to the `signal` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)

Comment: Well that's useful. I'm using a global variable and it works but still I long for a better approach. Thanks for the reference